# python-shell javascript not finding my Module

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x

I'm trying to call my Python script with python3. The script uses a third party library installed with pip3 called webuntis.

The python script works perfectly on the command line so no errors there.

**My Javascript code:**
const python = require('python-shell').PythonShell

```
python.run('./app/api/webuntis.py', {
    mode: "json",
    pythonPath: "/usr/bin/python3",

}, (err, results) => {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(results);
})
```

**The Error: It doesn't find packages, obviously**
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the **pycache** folder in the same directory didn't let my python script import anything. I had to delete the folder AND rename the file since the folder created itself at runtime.